# Bring Line ID which intersect with a point buffer in arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, intersect

[image: One point example]

In ArcPy, I want to take each point buffer one by one and check which two lines intersect with it and bring the `ObjectID` in order to use those two lines ID in this script.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("RoadCenterline",["SHAPE@"], "objectId=432") as uCursor:
     with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("RoadCenterline",["SHAPE@"], "objectId=442") as sCursor:
         row1 = uCursor.next() #get first record
         row2 = sCursor.next() #get first record
         geom = row1[0].union(row2[0])
         row1[0] = geom
         arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(geom,"in_memory\merged")
         uCursor.updateRow(row1) # TypeError: cannot read geometry sequence. expected list of floats
del uCursor
del sCursor
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. Are you asking for a script that identifies the objectIDs that will feed into your update/search cursors? In the script you show I believe a union of two lines that cross (this is different to overlapping) each other results in a point, so you are trying to store a point in something that is a polyline, hence your TypeError.

Comment: `Geometry.union()` is the correct operator to dissolve two features of the same geometry class. I certainly wouldn't use nested cursors to accomplish this, and the CopyFeatures seems unnecessary (from a snippet standpoint).

Comment: I already know that union will be the correct operator but after selecting all line that intersect with each buffer how can I let arcpy to identify the object ID of these tow line to do union then. @Hornbydd

Comment: I already know that union will be the correct operator but after selecting all line that intersect with each buffer how can I let arcpy to identify the object ID of these tow line to do union then. @Vince

Comment: Assuming that you can know both objectid values seems to be your issue here. You haven't structured your code to search for neighbors, so the code snippet doesn't reflect an attempt to resolve the task. ArcPy isn't imbued with intelligence; it can only identify matching features if you tell it how. What have you tried? What problem was encountered?

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation of the question:  I have polygons and lines.  Each line can intersect 0, 1, or 2 polygons.  If two lines both intersect a polygon, I want to merge them together, such that in this sketch all 4 lines would become one multipart line feature.

The easy way to do this would be to snap all the lines to the points at the center of the buffers, or to each other's endpoints, then do Dissolve or Unsplit Lines.

But let's get carried away and suppose we don't want to do that.  Is there a simpler way to do this?  Probably, but here's my attempt.  The situation:

[image]

I would start with a spatial join to write the object ids of every buffer polygon to the line(s) it touches.

```
line_fc = 'lines'
poly_fc = 'buffers'
out_fc = 'memory\\sj'
buffer_oid_field = 'buffer_oids'
delim = ','

fm = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm.addInputField(poly_fc, 'OBJECTID')
fm.mergeRule = 'Join'
fm.joinDelimiter = delim
out_field = fm.outputField
out_field.name = buffer_oid_field
out_field.aliasName = buffer_oid_field
out_field.type = 'String'
out_field.length = 255
fm.outputField = out_field

fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()
fms.addFieldMap(fm)

arcpy.analysis.SpatialJoin(
    target_features=line_fc,
    join_features=poly_fc,
    out_feature_class=out_fc,
    join_operation='JOIN_ONE_TO_ONE',
    join_type='KEEP_ALL',
    field_mapping=fms,
    match_option='INTERSECT')
```

According to our picture, our output polyline feature class would look like:

```
 OBJECTID | buffer_oids
----------|------------
 1        |  1
 2        |  1,2
 3        |  2,3
 4        |  3
```

If literally all you wanted to do is get the object ids of the lines touching each buffer as your question states, you could do a spatial join similar to this one but with the target/join features flipped, and modify the FieldMappings accordingly.  (A spatial join is often going to be faster than nested search cursors comparing every line to every buffer).  But I assumed there was more to this question so I'll continue:

Now we want to prepare a dictionary listing features we need to dissolve for each buffer, based on the `buffer_oid` they have in common.  We also need to separately keep track of the lines that didn't intersect any buffers, if present; they're still in the spatial join output because we did 'KEEP_ALL'

```
from collections import defaultdict

dissolve_dict = defaultdict(lambda: set())
lines_no_intsxn = []

with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_fc, ['OBJECTID', buffer_oid_field]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        line_oid = row[0]
        buffer_oids_str = row[1]

        if not buffer_oids_str:
            lines_no_intsxn.append(line_oid)
            continue

        buffer_oids = [int(i) for i in buffer_oids_str.split(delim)]
        for buffer_oid in buffer_oids:
            dissolve_dict[buffer_oid].add(line_oid)
```

Our dictionary for this example should look like:

```
dissolve_dict = {
    1: {1, 2},
    2: {2, 3},
    3: {3, 4}
}
```

Finally, we can combine all these sets to get our end result:

```
final_set_list = []
master_set = None
for dissolve_set in dissolve_dict.values():
    if not master_set:
        master_set = dissolve_set
        continue
    
    if master_set.intersection(dissolve_set):
        master_set.update(dissolve_set)
    else:
        final_set_list.append(master_set)
        master_set = dissolve_set

final_set_list.append(master_set)
```

Our list for this example should look like:

```
final_set_list = [{1, 2, 3, 4}]
```

Now we do the "dissolve" to get the final list of geometry objects.

```
geoms = []
for final_set in final_set_list:
    line_oids_str = ','.join([str(i) for i in final_set])
    where = 'OBJECTID IN (' + line_oids_str + ')'
    
    dissolve_geom = None
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_fc, 'SHAPE@', where) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            geom = row[0]

            if not dissolve_geom:
                dissolve_geom = geom
                continue

            dissolve_geom = dissolve_geom.union(geom)

    geoms.append(dissolve_geom)
```

And finally we need to add in the lines that didn't touch any buffers, if present.

```
if lines_no_intsxn:
    no_intsxn_oid_str = ','.join([str(i) for i in lines_no_intsxn])
    where = 'OBJECTID IN (' + no_intsxn_oid_str + ')'
    
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(out_fc, 'SHAPE@', where) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            geom = row[0]
            geoms.append(geom)
```

Now you have the `geoms` list and can insert them into a feature class or whatever.